# Defining a variable using head and cut

Tags: bash, variables

might be an easy question, I'm new in bash and haven't been able to find the solution to my question.

I'm writing the following script:

```
for file in `ls *.map`; do 

ID=${file%.map}

convertf -p ${ID}_par #this is a program that I use, no problem

NAME=head -n 1 ${ID}.ind | cut -f1 -d":" #Now: This step is the problem: don't seem to be able to make a proper NAME function. I just want to take the first column of the first line of the file ${ID}.ind
```

It gives me the return 
     line 5: bad substitution
any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- `` for file in `ls *.map` `` does not do what you want. It will fail e.g. if any of the filenames contains a space or `*`, but there's more. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 for details.

  You should just use `for file in *.map` instead.
- ALL_UPPERCASE names are generally used for system variables and built-in shell variables. Use lowercase for your own names.

That said,

```
for file in *.map; do 
    id="${file%.map}"
    convertf -p "${id}_par"
    name="$(head -n 1 "${id}.ind" | cut -f1 -d":")"
...
```

looks like it would work. We just use `$( cmd )` to capture the output of a command in a string.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, that's what I needed.  Thanks for your advice regarding the names in small caps and the 'ls *.map', I saw it in the script of a co-worker and recycled it, not knowing how useful/useless it would be.

Comment: @PGen If you can do it without causing offense, point your co-worker at that BashPutfalls entry -- looping over `ls`'s output is a really common bad idea, and should be stamped out as much as possible. BTW, also note that it's a good idea to add `[ -e "$file" ] || continue` as the first line inside the loop, in case there are no matching files (this is mentioned a ways down in the BashPitfalls discussion).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Or enable `nullglob`.

Comment: @melpomene That works too, but you have to be careful to turn it off or it can cause unexpected consequences later (and it only works in `bash`, not some other shells). Adding the test line is a bit clunky-looking, but IMO it's more robust.

Comment: I can't actually think of a time when I would want the literal pattern if it doesn't match.

Comment: @chepner There are a number of commands that take a list of files to operate on, but do something different if no files are given. Take `grep "pattern" /some/path/*.txt` -- if there're no matches, it'll read from stdin instead of just returning failure. Similarly, `ls -l /some/path/*.jpg` will cheerfully list everything in the current directory instead of the intended (lack of) files.